# Get Child Directory from Path

Tags: c#, path

How can i split the Path to get the Value CustomCompanyNames?

`C:\Project\v4.0\Tool\Custom\CustomCompanyNames\Template\bin\file\file.xml`

How can i get the Value?

Comment: refer string.Split

Comment: Thx, i looking for a way to split the path. Do you know a pattern to get the Value CustomCompanyNames ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/getting-the-folder-name-from-a-path

Comment: Could you add expected value to the question? Is it `Template\bin\file\file.xml`? If true, then it sounds like you are trying to get relative path (relative to `CustomCompanyNames`).

Comment: Expected value ist: CustomCompanyNames, i dont need the relativ path :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get for a specific file the parent directory of "Template" directory you can try this:

```
public string GetTemplateDirectoryParentName(string filePath)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = fileInfo.Directory;
    while(directoryInfo.Name != "Tempalte")
    {
        direcotryInfo = direcotryInfo.Parent;
    }
    return direcotryInfo.Parent.Name;
}
```

You can do it the other way by getting the child directory of "Custom" directory:

```
public string GetTemplateDirectoryParentName(string filePath)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = fileInfo.Directory;
    while(directoryInfo.Parent.Name != "Custom")
    {
        direcotryInfo = direcotryInfo.Parent;
    }
    return direcotryInfo.Name;
}
```

Comment: You have typos in your second block.