# Get highest path of a file

Tags: c#, path

I have a path like

```
string path = @"C:\foo\bar\temp\test\file.txt";
```

and want to get the foldername of the file - in this case the expected result is `"test"`.

Is there a build in way which is more elegant compared to `path.SubString(path.LastIndexOf('/')` etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the folder name from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/getting-the-folder-name-from-a-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of the file's parent directory by using the [`DirectoryInfo.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
new FileInfo(@"C:\foo\bar\temp\test\file.txt").Directory.Name
```

This will return 'test' from the example.

Comment: Well there's more or less the same answer there, just they load `DirectoryInfo` using a `DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename))`, instead of loading through file.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Path.GetDirectoryName (path);`

```
string path = "C:/foo/bar/yourFile.txt";
string folderName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
```

OR

```
string path = "C:/foo/bar/yourFile.txt";
string folderName = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
```

OR

```
string path = "C:/foo/bar/yourFile.txt";
string folderName = new FileInfo(path).Directory?.Name;
```

More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use [the static `Path` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.7.2):

`Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` and then take `Path.GetFileName()`.

This example returns what you asked for:

```
var fileName = @"C:\foo\bar\temp\test\file.txt";
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
var directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryPath); 
Console.WriteLine(directoryName);
```

Result: test