# How to print only the last folder's name of array

Tags: c#, arrays, directory, directoryinfo

The code looks like this:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\a\folder");
DirectoryInfo[] Dirs = d.GetDirectories();
foreach (var item in Dirs)
{ 
Console.WriteLine("The folders:{0}", item.ToString());
}
```

And it prints this:

**The folders: c:\a\folder\foldertozip**

But I only want to print **foldertozip**. How can I do that? 
Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You have to use "item.Name"

Comment: Thanks, absolutely what I was looking for.

Comment: Even though your code is printing "Console.WriteLine("The folders:{0}", item.ToString());" is printing as excepted ..  What was wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change `item.ToString()` to [`item.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.name?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_Name):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\a\folder");
DirectoryInfo[] Dirs = d.GetDirectories();
foreach (var item in Dirs)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("The folders:{0}", item.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split and get the last

```
item.ToString().Split("\\").Last();
```

Or even better,  use the `DirectoryInfo.Name` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.name?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_Name

> This Name property returns only the name of the directory, such as "Bin". To get the full path, such as "c:\public\Bin", use the FullName property.

Answer (score 1):

item -> will hold the whole directory so, doing toString isn't the option if you want the Name of Folder/SubFolder only

see there is method "Name" which you can use it by calling as **item.Name** in console.WriteLine() , instead of item.toString()

```
foreach (var item in Dirs)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("The folders:{0}", item.Name());
}
```

or you can do this : [Getting the folder name from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/getting-the-folder-name-from-a-path)

I would probably use something like:

```
string path = "C:/folder1/folder2/file.txt";

string lastFolderName = Path.GetFileName( Path.GetDirectoryName( path ) );
```

The inner call to GetDirectoryName will return the full path, while the outer call to GetFileName() will return the last path component - which will be the folder name.

This approach works whether or not the path actually exists. This approach, does however, rely on the path initially ending in a filename. If it's unknown whether the path ends in a filename or folder name - then it requires that you check the actual path to see if a file/folder exists at the location first.

Comment: `Name` is a property, not a method.

Comment: sorry for that , i meant property only. Thanks for correction :)