# Ho to Get Fom A Folder Path Folder Name

Tags: c#

I'm using C# to get the Name of the folder Is this a corect way to implement this.

For the moderators no this question hase not been answered (sf)

`string folderName = Path.GetFileName(enteredPath);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string folderPath = @"C:\Users\Ron\Documents\MyFolder\";
    string folderName = Path.GetFileName(folderPath.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)); // Trim any trailing separators
```

In this code, folderPath is the path to the folder, and `Path.GetFileName()` is used to extract the folder name from that path. The `TrimEnd()` method is used to remove any trailing directory separators (\ on Windows) from the path before extracting the folder name.

Answer (score 2):

string path = "C:/folder1/folder2/file.txt";

string lastFolderName = Path.GetFileName( Path.GetDirectoryName( path ) );

see:
[Getting the folder name from a full filename path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/getting-the-folder-name-from-a-full-filename-path)

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet would return the files name, not the directories name.

You can either do

```cs
string folderName = Path.GetFileName( Path.GetDirectoryName( enteredPath ) );
```

or

```cs
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(enteredPath);
var dirName = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
```